# Вчера и завтра

Tags: этимология

Со словом "вчера" более-менее понятно: судя по всему, оно происходит от слово "вечер". А вот как быть с "завтра"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ВЕЧЕР** «часть суток от конца дня до начала ночи». Общеслав. Соврем. слово развилось из др.-рус. вечеръ — тожд., в нем утрачен слаб, ъ (в укр. вёчьр—тожд. i из е (о) в закрытом слоге). Др.-рус. *вечеръ* восходит к праслав. *vьčегъ «вечер», собств. «темень, потемнение». Оно образовано с суф. -еr- от* vec- < и.-е. *vek- «темнеть» (перед гласн. переднего ряда е к > с). Из формы род. п.* вьчера *развилось нареч.* вчера *— как бы «прошлого вечера», «накануне сегодняшнего дня» (в укр. вчора — тожд. после ч е > о). От нареч. вчера прибавлением -сь создана известная в диал. форма* вчерась *«вчера». От нее с пом. суф. относит. прил. -ьн- при чередов. перед ь c//ш создано прил.* вчерашний* «который был вчера».

**ЗАВТРА** «на следующий день после сегодняшнего». Соврем. форма этого слова употребляется в рус. и укр. языках (ср. блр. заўтра «завтра»). Она развилась из др.-рус. и ст.-сл. заутра «завтра» вследствие изменения у > в (как диал. вдарить вместо ударить). Две формы данного слова — *заутра* и *завтра* — параллельно употреблялись в рус. яз. и в XIX в. Первая — в поэт. речи, вторая — в обиходно-разговорной. Древн. форма *заутра* возникла из сочетания предл. *за* и сущ. *утро* в род. п. Это сочетание выражало знач. времени — «утром, рано» (ср. болг. за рана; укр. разг. загодя «заранее», за години «в хорошую погоду»), затем — «то, что следует после утра» > «следующий день» (рус. диал. завчера, откуда позавчера «накануне вчерашнего дня»). Со словом утро связано также сущ. *завтрак* «утренняя еда».

Comment: >Соврем. слово развилось из др.-рус. вечеръ — тожд., в нем утрачен слаб, ъ (в укр. вёчьр—тожд. i из е (о) в закрытом слоге). 

На украинском не "вёчьр", как вы написали. Буквы Ё в укр.яз. вообще не существует. :)
Правильно -- **"вечір"**. Читается [вЭчир].

Comment: >На украинском не "вёчьр", как вы написали  

Это, видимо, проблема оцифровки.

Answer (score 2):

Приведу забавный факт, который косвенно относится к теме вопроса. В хинди (один из языков Индии) понятия "вчера" и "завтра" обозначаются одним словом - "кал". Это связано с тем, что процесс модернизации не сильно затронул индусов, и те из них, чьим единственным языком является хинди, всё ещё живут в эпохе Премодерн. Одна из характерных черт этой эпохи - циклическое социальное время. Линейное же время, которое пришло ему на смену, появилось только в эпоху Модерна. Для нас естественным является именно линейное время, поэтому мы очень чётко разграничиваем вчера и завтра. В нашем представлении это не просто то, что выходит за рамки сегодня. Мы осмысляем время линейно. Для нас есть прошлое, в котором было вчера, и будущее, в котором будет завтра. Но, очевидно, так было не всегда. Когда-то мы тоже были как индусы. У нас тоже не было прошлого более далёкого, чем прошедший день, и будущего более далёкого, чем день следующий. Видимо, слова "вчера" и "завтра" образовались как раз в те времена. С учётом того, что прошедшее и будущее время в нашем языке выражается изменением формы слова, удобно исходить из того, что если кто-то днём говорит о вечере в прошедшем времени, то значит он говорит о предыдущем дне, а если он говорит в будущем времени об утре, то значит речь идёт о дне следующем.

Comment: Можно узнать источник? 
Мне подобное мне представляется совершенно невозможным. Напоминает плохой анекдот про лингвистов.
Т.е. я не ставлю под сомнение сам факт, его легко проверить с помощью того же гугла, но объяснение с помощью каких-то философий совершенно фантастическое. Думаю, там все проще, всё объясняется чисто грамматически. В основу понятия кладется не точка отсчета "сегодня", а разница между сегодня и искомой датой. Это легко проверить, задав в переводчике позавчера - после завтра, три дня назад - через три дня и т.д.

Comment: Погуглите не только на сам факт, но и на понятия "социальное время", "Модерн", "Премодерн".

Comment: Понятно. Переходим на хамство.
ЗЫ Надеюсь, что Вы тут ненадолго.

Comment: Хамство? Я всего лишь не дал себя затроллить и втянуть в дискуссию, предмет которой мне совершенно не интересен. На тот случай, если он интересен вам отдельно от меня в роли жертвы троллинга, я дал вам основные ключевые слова для гугления.

ЗЫ Не надейтесь... Но я в свою очередь надеюсь, что пересекаться мы с вами не будем.

Comment: Объясняю. Не для Вас, разумеется. С Вами мне все понятно. Посылать искать в интернете то, на что автор ссылается, не имея о том ни малейшего представления, - это все равно, что посылать на три буквы. Так принято считать на большинстве известных мне форумах.   

Начинать дисскуссию о предмете, который автору неинетересен только ради того, чтобы послать первого заинтересовавшегося - тем более.  

ЗЫ Не надейтесь. Пересекаться со мной вы тут будете постоянно. Я обожаю изводить троллей их же методами.

Comment: Если бы вы и правда заинтересовались предметом, то просто погуглили бы. Вся информация есть уже на первой странице гугловой выдачи.

Comment: Есмли бы вы денйствительно хотели нормального общения, то не продолжали бы хамить.

Comment: Очнитесь! Этот сайт создан не для общения и не для дискуссий. Это не форум, а база знаний.

Comment: @behemothus, мне кажется, Вы слишком строги. Человек действительно хотел поделиться информацией, почему Вы восприняли это как хамство? Вам не нравится конкретно Дугин, или вообще попытки Вас "образовать"?  

Лично я дугинских теорий не знаю, про циклическое время читала только у Хюбнера в "Истине мифа". Но, конечно, эта цикличность не доходила до периода в 1 день, она включает хотя бы сезоны года.

Comment: Если отрицать влияние философии на слова, сложно приблизится к  истине. Не всегда слово образуется по сухим правилам: простой человек пытается выразить эмоцию, старается передать то, что он переживает, собеседнику. Благодаря этому и рождаются новые формы слов, потому что людям понравилась искренность, прозвучавшая в них когда-то. Например: "Дай мне немного хлеба!" и "Дай мне малёха хлебушка!" Понятно, что слово "малёха" в литературном русском не встречается, но в разговорном употребляется довольно часто.Со временем, с чьей-то лёгкой руки, оно преспокойно может перекочевать и в литературу.

Answer (score 1):

Кстати, в татарском языке наблюдается похожее соответствие:

- утро - иртә
- завтра - иртәгә
- вечер - кич
- вчера - кичә

Comment: Не совсем. Эти слова похожи, но различны.

Comment: И что? Какие слова различны?   
Вчера и вечер - тоже похожи, но различны. Как и "за(у/в)тра" - "утро"  

Если применить тут правила склонения, то иртәгә дословно будет "к утру", "в направлении утра". Правда, из "кич" таким же образом получилось бы "кичкә". Может, так и было, только чк превратилось в ч.

Comment: Возможно, я не совсем удачно выразился. 
Просто в вопросе не шла речь о полном соответвии. А связь слов вчера и вечер, завтра и утро вполне можно проследить во многих языках.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. Но с татарским еще более удивительно, ведь он из другой группы, не индоевропейской! Получается глобальное единомыслие ;-))

Answer (score 1):

Рт--   исходное труд работа (( ратник  страда  утро ретиво )
 А татарское утро не предполагает  обратное прочтение -РТ-   =  -ТР- .?
 Это к идее бинарности исходных языков .Вероятность создания бинарных слов не теряющих сиысл от обратного прочтения . Это религиозная идея предполагающая период расхождения и объединения языков - до ВаВиЛона -в период ВВЛ - после. Наиболее вероятен бин арабского и древнерусского. Пример- КоРаН = НаРоК . Татарское  иРТе = уТРо. Ивритское Гой= йоГ. Здесь согласные могут в основном менять смысл слова а гласные как менее склонные к изменению сохраняют смысл корня.

Comment: >Это к идее бинарности исходных языков .  
  
А что это такое?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы понять этимологию этих слов, стоит продвинуться в уточнении того, что такое вечер и что такое утро: заХОД и восХОД солнца. Есть слово Заря, утренняя и вечерняя. Т.е. "на заре" - это и утром, и вечером. Естественно, что в ряде языков эти слова будут близки, как в хинди или русском.

Comment: Чушь полная. Чтобы не сказать "задорновщина". С какого боку тут заря? Естесвенно, что ничего в хинди и в русском ближе быть не может. ))) Кроме того, что это индоевропейские языки.

Comment: Я дополнил линию рассуждений, которую обозначил Shamov. Вы не поняли ни того, что сказал он, ни того, о чем сказал я, поскольку не дали себе возможности подумать. Заря при том, что как и в хинди, может быть использовано одно слово для обозначения вечернего и утреннего времени. 
Если вам не понятно, что не удивительно, то это не значит, что говорящий несет чушь. Ведите себя прилично.

Answer (score 0):

В  современном  русском языке утром - заря, вечером - вечерняя  заря. Есть  примеры,  когда  вечерняя  заря  определялась  только  по  контексту ?

Comment: Бросьте. Первое же, что на ум приходит:

Там, вдали за рекой,  
Загорались огни,
В небе ясном  
_**Заря**_ догорала,  
Сотня юных бойцов  
Из будённовских войск  
На разведку  
В поля поскакала.

Comment: В  первом  случае  вечер  определяется  по  контексту. В  втором  - сокращение  фразеологизма ( возможно ).

Comment: > Одна заря сменить другую спешит, дав ночи полчаса.

Comment: >В первом случае вечер определяется по контексту  

А вы что просили?

>Есть примеры, когда вечерняя заря определялась только по контексту ?

Я чего-то не понимаю?
Насчет фразеологизма - не знаю право. Тут же в прямом значении. Но даже если так и это действительно фразеологизм, это что-то меняет в постановке вопроса?

Comment: Я  просил  найти  примеры,  где  вечерняя  заря  не  требует  определения, так  как  объясняется  контекстом - вы  нашли. А  что  касается  фразеологизма,  то  на  них  трудно  опираться  -  у  них  может  быть  своя  история.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "вечер" происходит от слова "ветшать" в значении "стареть, угасать". По-видимому, в древности слово могло звучать как "ветшер" с переходом "тш" в "ч".
Слово "завтра" означает то, что наступает за утром, после утра, то есть "следующий день".

Answer (score 0):

"Вечер происходит от слова "ветшать" в значении стареть, угасать"

а как же ВЕЧность? ВЕЧЕ?

Comment: Интересное замечание! В санскрите есть слова: "вачана" - вещание, речь, и "вача" - говорить. Вече, на мой взгляд, явно оттуда, а вот с вечностью...

Comment: а мне думается, что ВЕТхий - из семантического гнезда с ВЕТ, ВИТа, ВЕДа (воля, жизнь, знание). В значении "поживший". Там же - соВЕТ, ВЕЧе. В значении "объединенной воли, знания" (Ваш вариант с ВАЧА не конфликтует с моим, говорить - это ведь проявлять волю и знание). Оттуда же ответвляется ВЕК (сила, мощь), и, наконец, ВЕЧность (способность к силе, к воле, к жизни).
А вот ВЕЧер... По моей логике - из той же тусовки, но что же значит это словечко, если даже "утро вечера мудренее"... =) Не получается почувствовать...

Comment: вроде бы, все просто:
СТ - как СТояние. Тогда, воСТок и веСТок. Два солнечных хода. ВО - вверх, ВЕ - вниз? 
Тогда, ВЕЧер = ВЕСТер = время ВЕСТока (заката) солнца.
Но, смотрите:
WEST (нем, англ) - запад, закат
ВЕСТЬ (ВЕШТ) - опытный, мудрый = ВЕЩИЙ
ВЕЩЬ (ВЕЧЬ) - сущий, бодрствовать
ВЕЧЕР - время ВЕСТока солнца...
Получается, что семантически ВЕЧЕР связан с ВЕСТью (мудростью). Но как? Не могу почувствовать...

Comment: кажется, дело в нечетком звене у меня: ВЕСТ-закат -- ВЕЧЬ (ВЕСТЬ)-сущий, бодрствование...
Получается, что "бодрствовать" близко по смыслу к "закату". Это и смущает..
А может, бодрствование (существование) - это состояние ДО заката (вестока) Солнца? Тогда ВЕСТер=ВЕЧер - это время, до которого длится бодрствование? Как-то так =)